# Can I get Maven Findbugs plugin to print error codes?

Tags: maven, findbugs

I'm currently getting this error

```
[INFO] com.xenoterracide.AbstractEntityBase.equals(Object) is unusual [com.xenoterracide.AbstractEntityBase] At AbstractEntityBase.java:[line 34]
```

but I think the message is a little less than useful, especially for looking up. I found the code[`EQ_UNUSUAL`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/allBugDescriptions.html#EQ_UNUSUAL) by doing a find on the page for "unusual".

Is there any way I can get the messages to include the codes?

Comment: Similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084935/how-to-configure-gradle-findbugs-plugin-to-provide-more-description-for-bugs