# How to configure Gradle findbugs plugin to provide more description for bugs?

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

Is there a way to add or link to more bug descriptions in the report?

I mean good explanations of errors like `RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_WOULD_HAVE_BEEN_A_NPE` like in the GUI mode.

Some bug titles are not immediately clear.

Example for a description:

> `RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_WOULD_HAVE_BEEN_A_NPE` : A value is checked
>   here to see whether it is null, but this value can't be null because
>   it was previously dereferenced and if it were null a null pointer
>   exception would have occurred at the earlier dereference. Essentially,
>   this code and the previous dereference disagree as to whether this
>   value is allowed to be null. Either the check is redundant or the
>   previous dereference is erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Violations Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-gradle-plugin) to do that.

It can accumulate a bunch of report tools and present it nicely in the build log.

```
...
se/bjurr/violations/lib/example/OtherClass.java
╔══════════╤════════════╤══════════╤══════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Reporter │ Rule       │ Severity │ Line │ Message                                            ║
╠══════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Findbugs │ MS_SHOULD_ │ INFO     │ 7    │ Field isn't final but should be                    ║
║          │ BE_FINAL   │          │      │                                                    ║
║          │            │          │      │                                                    ║
║          │            │          │      │    <p>                                             ║
║          │            │          │      │ This static field public but not final, and        ║
║          │            │          │      │ could be changed by malicious code or              ║
║          │            │          │      │         by accident from another package.          ║
║          │            │          │      │         The field could be made final to avoid     ║
║          │            │          │      │         this vulnerability.</p>                    ║
╟──────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Findbugs │ NM_FIELD_N │ INFO     │ 6    │ Field names should start with a lower case letter  ║
║          │ AMING_CONV │          │      │                                                    ║
║          │ ENTION     │          │      │                                                    ║
║          │            │          │      │   <p>                                              ║
║          │            │          │      │ Names of fields that are not final should be in mi ║
║          │            │          │      │ xed case with a lowercase first letter and the fir ║
║          │            │          │      │ st letters of subsequent words capitalized.        ║
║          │            │          │      │ </p>                                               ║
╚══════════╧════════════╧══════════╧══════╧════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Summary of se/bjurr/violations/lib/example/OtherClass.java
╔══════════╤══════╤══════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ Reporter │ INFO │ WARN │ ERROR │ Total ║
╠══════════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║ Findbugs │ 2    │ 0    │ 0     │ 2     ║
╟──────────┼──────┼──────┼───────┼───────╢
║          │ 2    │ 0    │ 0     │ 2     ║
╚══════════╧══════╧══════╧═══════╧═══════╝


Summary
╔════════════╤══════╤══════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ Reporter   │ INFO │ WARN │ ERROR │ Total ║
╠════════════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║ Checkstyle │ 4    │ 1    │ 1     │ 6     ║
╟────────────┼──────┼──────┼───────┼───────╢
║ Findbugs   │ 2    │ 2    │ 5     │ 9     ║
╟────────────┼──────┼──────┼───────┼───────╢
║            │ 6    │ 3    │ 6     │ 15    ║
╚════════════╧══════╧══════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```